# "bash script.sh" vs "sh script.sh" w.r.t kill command - where sh is symlinked to bash

Tags: bash, shell, centos, kill

What's the difference in running the *bash* interpreter using the `bash` command itself vs `sh` command, where `sh` is also a symlink to bash?

The main difference I found is that, `kill` command behaves differently in `sh`. In `sh`, `kill` command wouldn't accept signal name, it would accept only signal numbers.

But in both `sh` vs `bash` run, `kill` command is a shell builtin. Seems like bash is behaving differently if invoked using `sh`.

Is there any documentation regarding this behaviour?

---

More info is given below:

#### script.sh

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

some_bg_program()
{
    sleep 10
}

some_bg_program&
pid=$!
kill -SIGTERM $pid
```

Output for running as `bash script.sh` and `sh script.sh`

```bsh
user@machine/tmp$ sh script.sh
script.sh: line 8: kill: SIGTERM: invalid signal specification
user@machine/tmp$ bash script.sh
```

(bash script.sh ran successfully and didn't throw any error).

Info regarding `bash` and `sh` commands:

```bsh
user@machine/tmp$ which bash
/usr/bin/bash

user@machine/tmp$ which sh
/usr/bin/sh

user@machine/tmp$ ls -l /usr/bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4 Aug  4  2020 /usr/bin/sh -> bash        # You can see the symlink here

user@machine~>ls -l /usr/bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 964608 Oct 30  2018 /usr/bin/bash

user@machine/tmp$ type sh
sh is hashed (/usr/bin/sh)
user@machine/tmp$ type bash
bash is hashed (/usr/bin/bash)
```

#### Info regarding the `kill` command in bash/sh

```bsh
user@machine/tmp$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
which kill
type kill

user@machine/tmp$ sh script.sh
/usr/bin/kill
kill is a shell builtin

sas@172.20.50.161/tmp>bash script.sh
/usr/bin/kill
kill is a shell builtin
```

So `kill` is a shell builtin in both of the cases

and finally, bash info:

```bsh
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
$ sh --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `bash` shell is started with the name `sh`, it will automatically be running in POSIX mode, as if started with the `--posix` option.

The "SEE ALSO" section of the `bash` manual refers to [http://tiswww.case.edu/~chet/bash/POSIX](http://tiswww.case.edu/%7Echet/bash/POSIX) for a description of the shell's POSIX mode.
That web page says, relating to your issue with the built-in `kill` utility:

> The following list is what's changed when 'POSIX mode' is in effect:
>
> [...]
>
> 37. The 'kill' builtin does not accept signal names with a 'SIG'
>     prefix.

So yes, the `kill` built-in utility does not accept signal names prefixed by `SIG` in POSIX mode.  You may want to use the signal names without the `SIG` prefix, i.e.

```bsh
kill -INT "$pid"
```

or

```bsh
kill -s INT "$pid"
```

This is also how [the POSIX specification for the `kill` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/kill.html) says it should be used.

Note that `kill -TERM "$pid"` would be the same as `kill "$pid"` as the `TERM` signal is the default signal that `kill` sends.

I would not use the signal numbers (with the exception for the `0` signal) as these are difficult to remember and, apart from a short list, differs between Unices.

Comment: Link into the manual: [6.11 Bash POSIX Mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode)